# curl, php response not being received called from CLI

Tags: php, curl

I am accessing an API via php and curl which makes calls that can take hours to complete. The php script call is made from the CLI. I know that the timeout for php is `set_time_limit(x)` and for curl,  `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`. All of these have been set correctly.

The php script runs, and I get an "Operation timed out" when the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` value is hit. The problem is the server has already sent a response before the timeout, which is not being received.

Are there any other places in which I can look for a timeout that is causing the response to not be received? Or any other suggestions as to how to debug why the response is getting lost?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not try Guzzle https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle ?

Comment: Did you ensure that your server side script is not timing out?.